# coloured bash prompt which uses a function

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-prompt, prompt

I need to make a bash prompt that uses the data returned by another function. I need the prompt to support colour.

Toy case:

```
fx() {
...some processing...
# x is the result of some processing
color=x
echo "\[$(tput setaf ${color})\]${data_from_processing}\[${tput sgr0}\]"
}
PS1='fx'
```

But the above solution doesn't seem to work. What I expected is 'data' in the specified color. But what I get is `\[\]<the correct data>\[\]`. It should be noted that `\]<the correct data\[` is in color.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell parses the value of `PS1` (which includes recognizing the special escape sequences `\[` and `\]`) before the command substitution is evaluated.

The simplest fix is to replace `\[` and `\]` with the actual bytes that the shell would:

```
q() { printf '\001%s\002123\001%s\002' "$(tput setaf 1)" "$(tput sgr0)"; }
```

However, I would recommend using `PROMPT_COMMAND` to assemble the value of `PS1` rather than embedding a command substitution:

```
q () { echo "\[$(tput setaf 1)\]123\[$(tput sgr0)\]"; }

make_prompt () {
  PS1="$(q):"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=make_prompt
```

Of course, you can fold the definition of `q` directly into the definition of `make_prompt` if like. Note that we aren't delaying the call to `q`; it is called immediately to create the value of `PS1` to use for each prompt.